# Edit generated 'importdata' function to import all files in directory in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, import, directory, edit

Seeking help from skillful Matlab users!

I'm kind of new to Matlab and hope somebody has the time to help me. I need to import some .txt-files from a directory. I have found a way to do this trough the import tool. There are some data using comma insted of dots, so `importdata` will not work, but the 'import data' tool does.

So i'm wondering (and hoping) if it is possible to edit the generated function to import all the files in the directory, in such a way as the single file is imported? I want each file to be imported as matrix variable (double). I want to import all the files in one process (loop). Also there are many files and they all have some 100 000 lines or so.

If someone see an easy way to do this i would appreciate the help. Please keep the explanation on a low level, as i'm quite novice. I get the following function using the 'import data' tool:

```
    function Streaming0x00x00158D00000E04621709201405 = importfile1(filename, startRow, endRow)
%IMPORTFILE1 Import numeric data from a text file as a matrix.
%   STREAMING0X00X00158D00000E04621709201405 = IMPORTFILE1(FILENAME) Reads
%   data from text file FILENAME for the default selection.
%
%   STREAMING0X00X00158D00000E04621709201405 = IMPORTFILE1(FILENAME,
%   STARTROW, ENDROW) Reads data from rows STARTROW through ENDROW of text
%   file FILENAME.
%
% Example:
%   Streaming0x00x00158D00000E04621709201405 =
%   importfile1('Streaming_0_x_0_0_x_00158D00000E0462_17-09-2014_05.32.24_part000.txt',
%   17, 137834);
%
%    See also TEXTSCAN.

% Auto-generated by MATLAB on 2015/02/04 09:28:07

%% Initialize variables.
delimiter = ';';
if nargin<=2
    startRow = 17;
    endRow = inf;
end

%% Read columns of data as strings:
% For more information, see the TEXTSCAN documentation.
formatSpec = '%s%s%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

%% Read columns of data according to format string.
% This call is based on the structure of the file used to generate this
% code. If an error occurs for a different file, try regenerating the code
% from the Import Tool.
textscan(fileID, '%[^\n\r]', startRow(1)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(1)-startRow(1)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'ReturnOnError', false);
for block=2:length(startRow)
    frewind(fileID);
    textscan(fileID, '%[^\n\r]', startRow(block)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
    dataArrayBlock = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(block)-startRow(block)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'ReturnOnError', false);
    for col=1:length(dataArray)
        dataArray{col} = [dataArray{col};dataArrayBlock{col}];
    end
end

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Convert the contents of columns containing numeric strings to numbers.
% Replace non-numeric strings with NaN.
raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = dataArray{col};
end
numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2));

for col=[1,2]
    % Converts strings in the input cell array to numbers. Replaced non-numeric
    % strings with NaN.
    rawData = dataArray{col};
    for row=1:size(rawData, 1);
        % Create a regular expression to detect and remove non-numeric prefixes and
        % suffixes.
        regexstr = '(?<prefix>.*?)(?<numbers>([-]*(\d+[\.]*)+[\,]{0,1}\d*[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1})|([-]*(\d+[\.]*)*[\,]{1,1}\d+[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1}))(?<suffix>.*)';
        try
            result = regexp(rawData{row}, regexstr, 'names');
            numbers = result.numbers;

            % Detected commas in non-thousand locations.
            invalidThousandsSeparator = false;
            if any(numbers=='.');
                thousandsRegExp = '^\d+?(\.\d{3})*\,{0,1}\d*$';
                if isempty(regexp(thousandsRegExp, '.', 'once'));
                    numbers = NaN;
                    invalidThousandsSeparator = true;
                end
            end
            % Convert numeric strings to numbers.
            if ~invalidThousandsSeparator;
                numbers = strrep(numbers, '.', '');
                numbers = strrep(numbers, ',', '.');
                numbers = textscan(numbers, '%f');
                numericData(row, col) = numbers{1};
                raw{row, col} = numbers{1};
            end
        catch me
        end
    end
end


%% Replace non-numeric cells with NaN
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) && ~islogical(x),raw); % Find non-numeric cells
raw(R) = {NaN}; % Replace non-numeric cells

%% Create output variable
Streaming0x00x00158D00000E04621709201405 = cell2mat(raw);
```

If something is unclear, please comment.

All help is useful, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If all files are the same, you can make a cell array of the filenames (NOT a standard array, they do not behave correctly on strings). Then you can loop over the cell array. For instance:

```
fname_arr = {'file1.txt','file2.txt'}; % your filenames go here
for k in length(fname_arr):
    filename = fname_arr{k};
    %% Open the text file.
    fileID = fopen(filename,'r');  % start of the relevant part of your codeblock
    <...>  % omitting the stuff in the middle of the code
    fclose(fileID) % end of the relevant part of your codeblock
    allDataArray{k} = DataArray
end
```

Then `allDataArray` is a cell array whose `k`th element contains the `DataArray` obtained from file `fname_arr{k}`.

Comment: Ok, a few dumb questions. First i make a cell array of the filenames. and then implement the above in my codeblock, right? And when you say "%Your filenames go here", what do you mean? Is that the cell array? 
Sorry for hopeless questions, but I'm not good at this. 

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. Yes, you make a cell array of the filenames and then loop over the array. I meant that `fname_arr` should be replaced with your cell array of filenames. I just assigned an example cell array for `fname_arr` to illustrate what it would look like if you type in the array by hand.

Comment: Very helpful. Could you maybe save a poor soul a couple of hours searching the internet and give me a guide to making a cell array of the file name. All file names are variations of the shown filename in the 'importfunction' above. and they are all i the same directory. Thanks again :)

Comment: The `dir` function can be used to return a struct array of data on the files in the folder. ("struct array" = an array of identical data structures.) Using a suitable regular expression as an argument to `dir`, you should be able to ensure that only the files of interest are listed in the struct array (examples in the `dir` documentation). Let's say the struct array is called `dir_output`, then you can write a `for` loop for `k = 1:length(dir_output)`. On each iteration, `dir_output(k).name` should give you the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tried something here. Implemented this in my function:

`output=(dir_output); 
for k=1:length(output);
filename = output{k}.name; 
%% Open the text file. fileID = fopen(filename,'r');`

where 'dir_output' is a struct, containing all the file names in the Directory. Also put in:

```
%% Close the text file. 
fclose(fileID); 
allDataArray{k} = DataArray;
end
```

Get this as error:

`>> function1 Undefined function or variable 'dir_output'. Error in function1 (line 30) output=(dir_output);`
Why???